# Create a Google Maps window in Flask using a shortened Google Maps link

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, google-api

I want to create a function that takes a shortened (shortcut) Google Maps link and displays the location on a Flask web page. The code somewhat works, but the output I get is in the wrong location.

This is my function:

```py
def show_mini_map(map_link):

    api_key=""

    # Expand link
    if 'goo.gl/maps' in map_link:
        response = requests.get(map_link)
        map_link = response.url
        print(map_link)

    # Extract latitude/longitude
    match = re.search(r'@([-0-9.]+),([-0-9.]+),', map_link)
    if match:
        lat = match.group(1)
        lon = match.group(2)
        print(lat)
        print(lon)
    else:
        logging.error(f'Invalid link: {map_link}')
        return 'Invalid Google Maps link'

    # URL
    mini_map_url = f'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={api_key}&q={lat},{lon}&zoom=15'

    # HTML
    html = f'<iframe width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="{mini_map_url}" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

    return html
```

The generated link is (map_link) is correct, but the latitude/longitude in it is different than the actual location, for example, it generates `(23.613952, 58.459783)` while the actual location is `(23.614050304553913, 58.46864471825494)` for https://goo.gl/maps/zmU33mYztCEs3G356.

Is there a function to take the correct points or another way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get the name of address, and used it to call it

```py
location = geolocator.reverse(f"{latitude}, {longitude}", language='en')
name = location.address

# create the mini map URL with the name of the location
mini_map_url = f'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key={api_key}&q={name}&zoom=15'
```